# Copy row if cell value equals and paste after with new line

Tags: vba, excel

I have code that allows me to copy a row of a table if it contains the word `SAVE_01` in my sheet `SAVE_01`.  The copied line is then pasted in the sheet `SAVE_03` but each new line identified with the keyword `SAVE_01` does not start after the previous one.

The new line detected and overwritten.

Do you know how to detect the last empty line and put the new one after?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Value = "SAVE_01" Then Target.EntireRow.Copy _
        Destination:=Sheets("SAVE_03").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End Sub
```

Comment: You are basing your last row on column A so check if column A of the copied row has something in it. If it doesn't, it will overwrite.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Perhaps it would help if you included examples of what you have and what you're want to have when finished.  Also, have you look at the existing questions/answers? There are many similar questions with answers like these: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=paste+first+empty  Also I assume you mean "the first empty line" (not the last).

Comment: Yes it's the first empty line ^^ I simply want that each new detection of the word "SAVE_01" in my sheet1 the line is automatically copy / paste in my sheet 3 in continuation (without crushing the preceding)

Comment: Try to qualify the Rows.Count I.E. (sheet(x).Rows.Count) otherwise it will assume you are referencing active sheets Rows.

Answer (score 0):

I tried like this :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Value = "SAVE_01" Then Target.EntireRow.Copy _
Destination:=Sheets("SAVE_03").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Worksheets("SAVE_03").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Worksheets("SAVE_03").Cells(lastrow, "A").Value = "*"

End Sub
```

it works but it's not clean and I have to put "*" to detect a character. Other worries if I have a shared cell on several lines it puts me an empty cell in the copy